Problem with integration by parts for a cumulative probability and probability density functions
In Keller (1974) paper titled “Optimum Checking Schedules for Systems Subject to Random Failure”, the author derives expected cost function for linear loss function case as follows:

The initial function:

$$\left( \frac{c_{0}c_{1}}{2}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\int ^{t_{1}}_{0}\left( F'\int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau +\left( F’\left( a-F\right) \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) dt$$
2 In the paper, the author states that after applying integration by parts to the first term, the above expression can be simplified to the below:
$$\left( \frac{c_{0}c_{1}}{2}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\int ^{t_{1}}_{0}\left( F’\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\dfrac{1-F+a-F}{\left( a-F\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}}dt$$
By comparing the two equations, I deduced that the first term’s integral must equal the following:
$$\int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau =\frac{1-F}{\left( F'\left( a-F\right) \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
The problem is that I don’t understand how the LHS integral results in RHS expression. Some additional details: F is cumulative probability function, everything else are constant.
Extra: I myself tried the following transformation but cannot continue:
$$\int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F’}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau =\int ^{t}_{0}F'\left( \frac{1}{F'\left( a-F\right) }\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau =\int ^{t}_{0}\frac{dF}{\left( F'\left( a-F\right) \right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}}=?$$

The equation does not hold when $t=0$ (unless $F(0)=1$)

@geetha290krm you seem to not understand the problem, please refer to Keller (1974), that way you will have better understanding

Wolfram alpha cannot solve the integral $\int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau$ analytically, so directly trying to integrate it must be wrong. Instead, what I tried thereafter seems to be much closer to the integration by parts:
$$\int ^{t_{1}}_{0}F'\left( \int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau \right)dt= \left[ v’=F’;v=F;u=\int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F’}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau ; u '=\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}\right] = \left. F\int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F’}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau \right| _{0}^{t_{1}}-\int _{0}^{t_{1}}F\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}dt = \left[ F\left( t_{1}\right) =1;F\left( 0\right) = 0;t_{0}\leq t\leq t_{1}\right] = \int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau -\int ^{t_{1}}_{0}F\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}dt =  \int ^{t_{1}}_{0}\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}dt -\int ^{t_{1}}_{0}F\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}dt = \int ^{t_{1}}_{0}(1-F)\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}} dt$$
If there are methods to directly integrate $\int ^{t}_{0}\left( \frac{F'}{a-F}\right) ^{\frac{1}{2}}d\tau$, please, share the solution in the comment to this answer!
